# Writing fortran ordered binary files from python

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, scipy

I have some python code which generates a 256^3 numpy array of data that I'd like to read in with a different fortran code.

This would be relatively easy if the numpy ndarray function tofile() had an option to write fortran ordered data, but it does not and will always write C-ordered data.  Is there an equivalent function (in scipy maybe?) that will do what I want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could [`transpose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.transpose.html) the array before writing it out.

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.asfortranarray()` could help you achieve your goal.

Assuming that `data` is a 256^3 numpy array, the code snippet is shown as follows

```py
import numpy as np

np.asfortranarray(data).tofile('.../.../fortran_unformatted_data.dat')
```